# How to increase storage capacity for Cosmos DB collection?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a Cosmos DB collection in the Standard pricing tier which I'm loading new data into. Yesterday, I got a "Storage quota for 'Document' exceeded" error, and when I checked the Scale tab, I saw that the default storage capacity is 100 GB. I thought there were no storage limit in the Standard pricing tier. How can I increase the storage capacity, since this collection is supposed to contain several TBs?

Answer (score 3):

I got a quick response from Microsoft on my support request that there are some issues with their auto-splitting operations which is limiting the storage scalability at the moment. Microsoft will manually raise the storage limit for me. Hopefully they will soon solve the auto-scaling, so we don’t have to monitor the collection size.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I increase the storage capacity, since this collection is supposed to contain several TBs?

Currently it only enables us to adjust throughput level under Scale blade on Azure portal after the collection is created.

[image]

If possible, you can create a new collection with ***Unlimited Storage Capacity***, and then [migrate data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data#a-idoverviewlaoverview-of-the-data-migration-tool) from your source collection to that new collection.

[image]

Besides, you can create a **SUPPORT REQUEST** to get help from support.

Comment: I created my collection with unlimited storage capacity, but the Scale tab still says 100 GB default storage capacity. So in my case unlimited seems to mean 100 GB. :) I will try to create a support request.

Comment: ``I will try to create a support request`` yes, sending a support request would be a way to get help to increase/modify the Storage Capacity of your collection,

Comment: @MagnusJohannesson please upvote and close the thread if it helped you, so that other will not look into it unless you have any specific concern.

Comment: In your case you have to increase the RU which intern increase storage. Take a look at point-7: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/10-things-to-know-about-documentdb-partitioned-collections/

Comment: I tried increasing the RU, but it did not increase the storage limit.

Comment: just ran into the same issue with the 1200 GB limit, though I did not receive any warning and red asterisk as you show in your screenshot. This 100 GB limit is very limiting and I can't believe they didn't say that upfront!